# Android : android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED on ICS and Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-intent

My application is listening to android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED..

Android :2.3

i am able to get the broadcast when my application is **Shut/Active** before Boot up.

Android : 4.0.3

I am **not** able to get the broadcast when my application is **Shut(Force Close**) before Boot up.
Reason is [as in this link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.

How do  i Over Come this??I want to get the broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED when the application is Shut as well.

Please help!!!

Comment: did u get a solution to this sir ?

Answer (score 3):

The only way is that user should open your app explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

add this flag

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);

I think it will work. Because i have faced the same problem.

Comment: Where do i add this Flag!!I am registering in AndroidManifest File!!

Comment: That would have worked(?) if OP was trying to send intent to stopped package. But his own app is in that state.