# Android app needs to be auto-restart after the phone power On

Tags: android

I need my app to be started automatically once after the phone reboot and Power-on.

I used the code provided at [AutoStart an Application at boot up](http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup) and now my android app starts automatically after the phone reboot (restart).

Now, consider that instead of doing a phone reboot, I have used **Phone power off (Shut phone down)** option. After the phone power on, my app is not started automatically as expected. Can you please explain what I have missed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static SharedPreferences aSharedSettings;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        aSharedSettings = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isUserLoggedIn = aSharedSettings.getBoolean(kEY.AUTHENTICATED, false); 
        if(isUserLoggedIn) 
        {
Intent aServiceIntent = new Intent(context, HomeView.class);
                aServiceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(aServiceIntent); 
}

    }
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Does it work as intended if you launch the application manually at least once before rebooting the phone, and not 'Force-close' it?

Have a look at:

[Android : android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED on ICS and Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775243/android-android-intent-action-boot-completed-on-ics-and-gingerbread)

[Boot Completed Regression Confirmed](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can try.

Firstly check that your app `installLocation` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is set to `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` this makes sure that the app is on the local storage. Apps installed to the sdcard will not receive the `BOOT_COMPLETE` intent.

Also I would remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` it is not necessary.

And the last thing you can try is using a full package name:

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" 
              android:name="com.myapp.receivers.BootUpReceiver" 
              android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I made all the 3 changes. But its not working. I am using HTC one V. For me, in HTC ONE V, my android app starts automatically after the phone reboot (restart). However, when I use "Phone power off (Shut phone down)", this BroadcastReceiver is not called, and the restarting is not working. So I feel, there is no problem with BroadcastReceiver.. I checked this with the other android models and found that the auto-restart works properly in 'Phone power off'. Only problem in HTC one V. Any suggestions please..

Comment: So put simply it works when rebooting but not when you come from "Powered Off">?

Comment: Yes Chris.. it works when rebooting but not when come from "Powered Off".

Comment: I can only see that as a device bug, there is no 'special' way to designate if you are coming from reboot/boot in the manifest. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

instead of

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />.
```

And also check the value of isUserLoggedIn.

Comment: Thanks Kumar. Tried this. But its still not working in Phone power off (Shut phone down) in HTC one V. However, in other model phones its working. Suggestions please..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a HTC device? If so, you may have a feature enabled called "Fast-Boot"

See this link for  details.

[Detect if HTC "Fast boot" is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658862/detect-if-htc-fast-boot-is-enabled)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. Yes I am using HTC one V. For me, in HTC ONE V, my android app starts automatically after the phone reboot (restart). However, when I use "Phone power off (Shut phone down)", this BroadcastReceiver is not called, and the restarting is not working. I checked this with the other android models (samsung and sony) and found that the auto-restart works properly in 'Phone power off'. Only problem in HTC one V. I tried ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_USER_PRESENT, but its not working. Help please..

Answer (score 1):

the name of the Activity from where you are starting your application, Add this line in your  tag.....And let me know it worked or not

```
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HomeView" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response samintechvalens.. I tried this, however, still its not working.